# DateRangePicker material ui value formatting

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, momentjs, date-fns

I am getting the value as Fri Oct 01 2021 14:17:20 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)

I want it to be 2021-10-01 00:00

How is it possible? Here is my code:

````
      ```const [value, setValue] = useState([null, null]);
           
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={DateAdapter}>
                <StaticDateRangePicker
                    displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"
                    allowSameDateSelection={true}
                    format="yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm"
                    calendars={1}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
                    renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => {}}
                />
            </LocalizationProvider>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used forEach to change the original array as both "value" and "newValue" are array type.

```
    const [value, setValue] = useState([null, null])

    const updatePendingValue = (newValue) => {
    newValue.forEach((element, index) => {
        if (newValue[index] != null) {
            newValue[index] = moment(element).format('yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm');
        }
    });

    setValue(newValue);
};

      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                <StaticDateRangePicker
                    displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"
                    allowSameDateSelection={true}
                    calendars={1}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(newValue) => updatePendingValue(newValue)}
                    renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => {}}
                />
            </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).